# AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute '_committed' - django

Tags: python, django

I need to create a record with a one-to-one relationship and another field, the model of the one-to-one relationship has a filefield, when I create it, it throws me the error of the title.

This is my code.
Models

```
class Proyecto(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nombre_p = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    descripcion_p = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    file_arff = models.FileField(upload_to='arff')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.file_arff)


class Escenario(models.Model):
    proyecto = models.ForeignKey(Proyecto)
    file_txt = models.FileField(upload_to='txt/')
```

View

```
id_proyecto = Proyecto.objects.get(pk=request.session['proyecto_id'])
escenario = Escenario(proyecto=id_proyecto, file_txt=file_txt)
            escenario.save()
```

throw me this error :  AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute '_committed'

Comment: I think you need to create your `escenario` object like so: `escenario = Escenario.objects.create(proyecto=id_proyecto, file_txt=file_txt)` and there would be no need to call `.save()`.

Comment: so I had it, It gave the same error

Comment: Red Cricket is right. I did it for you below.

Answer (score 0):

models

```
class Escenario(models.Model):
    proyecto = models.ForeignKey(Proyecto, related_name="xxxxx")
    file_txt = models.FileField(upload_to='txt/',  null=True, blank=True)
```

views

```
id_proyecto = Proyecto.objects.get(pk=request.session['proyecto_id'])
obj = Poyecto.objects.filter(id=id_proyecto)
file_txt = None #Or you can add a file here that you want to attach to the modal. 
if file_txt = None:
     instance = Escenario.objects.create(proyecto=obj)
else:
     instance = Escenario.objects.create(proyecto=obj, file_txt=file_txt)
for x in obj:
       instance.xxxxx.add(x)
```

Comment: sorry but, I dont understand the xxxxx.

Comment: it can be named anything: "foo", "thingy", "placeholder", "related_name_for_proyecto" ... I chose xxxxx b/c it was easy.

Comment: I also added it to the model here:
    proyecto = models.ForeignKey(Proyecto, related_name="xxxxx")

Comment: it does not work, throw this error :  Cannot assign "[<Proyecto: /media/vih.arff>]": "Escenario.proyecto" must be a "Proyecto" instance.   in this line : instance = Escenario.objects.create(proyecto=obj, file_txt=file_txt)

Comment: sorry, I meant this. The poyecto field has to equal the object, not just an ID. Try: instance = Escenario.objects.create(proyecto=obj, file_txt=file_txt) (I edited it above as well)

Comment: I realized that the error is by the field file_txt. how can you help me

Comment: Where is the file you are trying to save there as filetxt?  I assumed you had loaded it in the views already. You need to assign some sort of a file, or change the model to not require the field.  I'll edit above.

Comment: I take the file from disk.  ----- file_txt = saveTXT(result.encode('utf-8'), path_txt). ----     def saveTXT(result, path):
    f = open(path, 'w+')
    f.write(result)
    f.close()
    return f

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. Is the filing converting alright? Can you print it in the console and what not?

Comment: I fixed it, it's like this:  esc = Escenario.objects.create(Proyecto=proyecto_obj)
            esc.file_txt.save(file_txt.name, ContentFile(file_txt)).    --- thank you very much, you helped me a lot

Comment: Glad you figured it out!